# Fluid metro box

Tags: html, css

Following is my js fiddle in which I am populating the courses taken in a metro tile form. Problem is if text increases then the box doesnot increase its width accordingly. Also if courses name length increses the box should resize itself width wise accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/WFZ3d/

```
<div style="width: 400px;
">
<div style="
background-color:#2B547E; 
color: white;
padding: 20px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
">
    Courses
</div>
<div style="-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border:1px solid #CCC; padding:10px;">

<div style="margin:5px;padding:10px; background-color:#3ea055; color:white; font-size:20px;  width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-width:auto;
    ">Mathhhhh</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protip: separate your DOM elements and styles. Inline styles are not a good idea.

Your problem is that you're setting the width on the box. You need to change the box to be inline-block.

I updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/WFZ3d/2/

```
<div style="margin:5px;padding:10px; background-color:#3ea055; color:white; font-size:20px; height:60px; display: inline-block;">Mathhhhh</div>
```

Comment: I am just beta making, i'll make proper external css later... Moreover your update got messed up when courses goes to next line

Comment: adding a break between them will give you a desired effect. http://jsfiddle.net/WFZ3d/9/